# AWS Load Balancers and Strict Transport Security Header

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, http-headers, amazon-elb

I am supposed to send a response from my web service with an STS header, but the service itself sits behind an AWS ALB which terminates SSL and sends the traffic on via http. This seems to be a common scenario and likely not limited to AWS, i.e. many LB's have the capability to terminate SSL as this is a very useful feature!

I have read through some messages from people who have already had this issue and have not seen any answers that seem anything other than a workaround - it seems to me to be a catch 22 situation, the LB doesn't send it as it isn't within its remit (according to one response from AWS support) and the target web server can't add it coz that header can only be added to https responses which the web server is not processing!

So my question is, is the sts header really that important if my web service can only respond on an https endpoint (no http enpdoint, not even a redirect)? Or is it still vulnerable to things like mitm attacks etc?

thanks in advance

Comment: *"... the target web server can't add it coz that header can only be added to https responses"* - the header can be added to any responses, no matter if HTTP or HTTPS. But it has only effect if __the client__ receives this header with HTTPS. But since the client is on the other side of the load balancer it will actually receive the header with HTTPS.

Comment: yeah i guess i can force adding it in using one of the workarounds, but i am interested in understanding it a bit more hence my question about its importance. i don't completely understand everything that is going on - i was thinking that if there is a header that is forcing the client to use https but i only expose an https listener on the lb anyway, isn't the sts header redundant?

Comment: *"... force adding it in using one of the workarounds ..."* - I have no idea what kind of web application platform you have which explicitly needs "workarounds" to add a custom header. And HSTS does not enforce the client to use HTTPS __now__, it instead says that HTTPS should also be used __in the future__, even if a link explicitly says to use simple HTTP. This is to protect against something like [sslstrip](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41988/how-does-sslstrip-work).

Comment: doh! i understand now, there is a comment in your link that makes it obvious now why this is important - "Just because you can't connect to the site with HTTP doesn't mean you can't connect to the attacker with HTTP". many thanks steffen :)